# Find an orthonormal basis of R^3 such that the linear operator is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

> Let e be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $[L]_{e}$ is represented by
> \begin{equation}
> \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 2 & 2 & 2 \\
> 2 & 1 & 0 \\
> -2 & 0 & 3
> \end{array}\right)
> \end{equation}
> Find at least one orthonormal basis e' of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $[L]_{e'}$ is diagonal.

My attempt is to deduce a basis that makes the matrix diagonal then normalize it, but when I computed the e-values (By WolframAlpha), I got complex numbers. So I think I'm doing something wrong. Any help on how to solve this problem?

Comment: No. It cannot be solved since, as you wrote, that matrix has non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: I suspect the matrix was intended to be symmetric, either with $-2$ in the top right, or $2$ down the bottom left.

Comment: @TheoBendit I agree. In both cases, one gets three integer eigenvalues.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. For a moment, I doubted myself. If I may ask if the matrix has three distinct e-values. My idea was to find a basis that makes the linear operator diagonal (e-vectors) then I normalize the basis that makes it diagonal. Is it the right way?

Comment: If the matrix is symmetric then, yes, that is correct.